# power bi - dynamic mean value

Tags: powerbi

i have a data with 4 selections; Week, M, S and A. I have below code to run to calculate the mean of value per week.

```
N1 = (DIVIDE('table1'[Total_value], DISTINCTCOUNT('table1'[Week])))
```

Where

```
Total_value =  ( sum('table1'[value]))
```

It worked great until I introduced slicer of M, S and A. It shows always the total mean value and when I something is selected it does not update.

```
    table1
    Value   Week    M   S   A   Average
    1       1       A   A   1   3.5
    2       1       A   X   2   3.5
    3       1       A   A   3   3.5
    4       2       B   X   1   3.5
    5       3       B   C   2   3.5
    6       3       B   C   3   3.5
```

Comment: You need to write a measure instead of a calculated column since calculated columns cannot be responsive to slicers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following DAX measures. This works with every filters:

```
DistCountWeek = DISTINCTCOUNT('table1'[Week])

TotalValue = Sum('table1'[Value])

YourAverage = TotalValue / DistCountWeek
```

Depending on your data model in the table, you can maybe use just this measure:

```
Average = AVERAGE('table1'[Value])
```

If you drag and drop the measure (as value) and the week (as axis) in a bar chart, you can achieve the same like above.

Comment: I have had exactly the measures but still when data is filtered the average do not update.

Comment: @Kalenji As I mentioned already, dynamic filters and slicers **cannot** affect a calculated column. Are you still using calculated columns instead of measures?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read you can't use slicers against [calculated columns](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Dynamic-calculate-Measure-value-based-on-Slicer-Selection/m-p/564005#M266110); it was recommended to use [bookmarking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks) instead.

You may be able to achieve something similar using a measure instead, though.

Answer (score 0):

Below link to the paper Dynamic programming: Arithmetic, Geometric, Harmonic, and Power Means.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363488132_Dynamic_Programming_Arithmetic_Geometric_Harmonic_and_Power_Means

https://www.academia.edu/resource/work/86545241

https://github.com/calebnwokocha/manuscripts/blob/main/Dynamic%20Programming%20-%20Arithmetic%2C%20Geometric%2C%20Harmonic%2C%20and%20Power%20Means.pdf

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).